# Unexpected behaviour of len of dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I expected len(items_by_post) to return 100 but I am getting 101. Can someone explain why I am experiencing this behavior?

```
items_by_post = {}

for i in joined:
    if i['post_code'] in items_by_post:
        items_by_post[i['post_code']].append(i)
    elif len(items_by_post)<=100 and i['post_code'] not in items_by_post:
        items_by_post[i['post_code']]=items_by_post.get(i['post_code'],[])
        items_by_post[i['post_code']].append(i)
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Why are you expecting 100? `dict.__len__` is pretty simple: it returns the number of keys.

Comment: What is `joined`?

Comment: Your second branch checks if there are *up to* 100 elements in ``items_by_post``, then adds another one. Use ``len(items_by_post) < 100`` if you want there to be at most 100 elements *after* adding another one.

Comment: I will note that if you have 100 keys, and see a new key, you still add the new key as the 101st key.

Comment: As an aside, `collections.defaultdict` makes this much simpler. `items_by_post = collections.defaultdict(list)`, then `for i in joined: if len(items_by_post) > 100: break; items_by_post[i['post_code']].append(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code calls `append()` while `len(items_by_post) <= 100`. Therefore, when `len(items_by_post) == 100` your code will `append()` another item, increasing `len(items_by_post)` to `101`.

Comment: ``append`` increases the size of the lists inside ``items_by_post``, not of the outer ``items_by_post`` itself.